# Как отключить переброс переменной под аннотацию?

Tags: android-studio

Мне удобнее писать так

```
@BindView(R.id.tv) private TextView tv;
```

Но, при Ctrl+Alt+L переменная сбрасывается под аннотацию, то есть:

```
@BindView(R.id.tv)
private TextView tv;
```

Где в Android Studio настроить правила Reformat Code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File → Settings → Editor → Code Style → Java → Wrapping and Braces.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: большое спасибо, теперь буду знать где искать

Comment: @Flippy был рад помочь)